# Bcrypt in Moodle

Tags: php, moodle, bcrypt

I am looking to be able to use Bcrypt in moodle as, by default, Moodle only accepts SHA-1, MD5, Plain Text and Crypt one-way string hashing. I have done some research but I could only find an outdated patch for moodle that did not work.

Comment: Use it for what? The user passwords are bcrypted by default.

Comment: As in the external authentication for moodle